# Call lm with a model matrix instead of a formula

Tags: r, lm

I want to fit a linear model in R using `lm` to obtain coefficient estimates and p-values + p-value for total model fit (ANOVA-like), so basically the output from `summary.lm`.

The problem is that I want to use my own model matrix, instead of specifying it using a formula when calling `lm`.

I've tried using the underlying `lm.fit` function which allows for this, but then I loose the convenience of the `summary.lm` function, and I don't want to recalculate all the test statistics again myself.

Is there a way to 'trick' `lm` and give it a model matrix rather than a formula?

Thanks!

Comment: `as.data.frame(model_matrix)`?

Comment: also, try setting `class(lm.fit_object) <- "lm"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example using the built in BOD data frame:

```
# inputs
demand <- BOD$demand
mm <- model.matrix(~ Time, BOD) # model matrix

summary(lm(demand ~ mm + 0))
```

or

```
summary(lm(demand ~. + 0, as.data.frame(mm)))
```

Comment: And of course you can construct the matrix manually: mm <- cbind(1, BOD$Time) also works.

Comment: This works! The only thing that needs changing is the terms having the name of the model matrix as a prefix - but this should be easy to do afterwards

Comment: Is there an issue with removing the intercept beforehand?  Seems more intuitive as an `lm` input: `summary(lm(demand ~ ., as.data.frame(model.matrix(~ ., BOD)[, -1])))`

Comment: It depends on what you want and whether the model matrix already has an intercept.